# How can you calculate a loan amortization with numpy that has prepayments?

Tags: python, numpy, finance

Is there a way to amortize a loan with prepayments using numpy arrays?

For instance,

```
def amort(principal, interest, number_periods):
    per = np.arange(number_periods*12) + 1
    ipmt = np.ipmt(interest/12, per, number_periods*12, principal)
    ppmt = np.ppmt(interest/12, per, number_periods*12, principal)
    return [-sum(ipmt), sum(ppmt)]
```

Then if `x=amort(100000, 0.05, 15)` then `total_interest_paid=x[0]`.  Now is there a way to amortize a loan with prepayments with `np.ipmt` and `np.ppmt` functions? I wasn't sure how.  I tried `amort(100000+100, 0.05, 15)` but that only adds 100 to the principal. I would like a pure `numpy` implementation if it's even possible.

Comment: Can you please provide a [MCVE]?

Comment: Have a read of [this](http://pbpython.com/amortization-model.html) and come back with with more specific problems.